# Android Studio, Shared Preferences Set Text Color

Tags: android, colors, android-sharedpreferences

At the moment I am trying to run this lines of code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("Tell me");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    ;
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String s = sharedPreferences.getString("font_list", "null");
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/" + s);
    editText.setTypeface(face);

    String s2 = sharedPreferences.getString("font_size", "8");
    editText.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(s2));

    String s3 = sharedPreferences.getString("font_color", "#000");
    editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(s3));



   // File directory = new File(path);
  // directory.mkdirs();
}
```

- I am trying to set and store the colors that user choices to allow them to type in that color, but whenever I try to run the app or do anything within the app, it crashes because of the setTextColor function and the sharePreferences within the string for it.

here is logcat image

[image]

Comment: Can you share your logcat?

Comment: Everything works fine for the setting the text font and size. It crashes when i run the setting the text color for some reason.

Comment: logcat? not sure what that is, i'm new to android studio.

Comment: This is logcat, just an image from Google xD 
http://www.chengxuyuans.com/uploads/allimg/141214/1I5334612-0.png

Comment: Here's the one from my app, http://imgur.com/a/xAEe5

Comment: Logs of the application would be helpful! May be 's3' has some issues or something else.. Check and post logs.

Comment: Yup. Everything should be clear now, there maybe problem with parseColor xD Are you sure if s3 is a valid color?

Comment: could be that im putting "#000" for default color instead "#ff000000"?

Comment: Just add this line before 'editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(s3));':
Log.d("COLOR", s3);
And again watch your logcat, before those red line, there should be the value of s3 that causes the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you log cat image you have  **IllegalArgumentException exception**

You have color string which is not in correct format  see this **[Color.parseColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String))**

> Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int. If the
>   string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException exception.
>   Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following
>   names: 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan',
>   'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray', 'grey', 'lightgrey',
>   'darkgrey', 'aqua', 'fuchsia', 'lime', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive',
>   'purple', 'silver', 'teal'.

Change

```
String s3 = sharedPreferences.getString("font_color", "#000");
```

to

```
String s3 = sharedPreferences.getString("font_color", "#000000");
```

Comment: Do vote up as well, it indicates the answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
String s3 = sharedPreferences.getString("font_color", "#000000");
```

This would be proper. 
Else use `Color.NAME_OF_COLOR`,  many are covered here.

Answer (score 0):

In Android You need to provide either 6 or 8 HexaColor code.
As it supported RGB or ARGB.
every two character define value of once color while making final color.
Like:- #112233

```
11 define Red color with value 17 from (0 to 255 range)

22 define Green color with value 34 from (0 to 255 range)

33 define Blue color with value 51 from (0 to 255 range)
```

Same if you have alpha than define first two digit with alpha value:-
Like with 50% opacity same above color HexaValue will be:- #80112233

```
where 80 is 128 alpha value from (0 to 255 range)
```

So correct solution for your problem will be:-

```
String s3 = sharedPreferences.getString("font_color", "#000000");
```

instead of

```
String s3 = sharedPreferences.getString("font_color", "#000");
```